# Cordova: Android API 33 - FileReader: can't load file

Tags: android, angular, cordova, filereader

I am trying to get file content from FileReader. But it seems like FileReader is having an error, and I don't know what the error is:
Here are the details of the function I try to get the file content:

[This is property of file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag7GI.png]

This is function, I try get file content from FileReader

```
private static blobToBase64(blob) {
  console.log(blob);
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      console.log(reader.result);
      console.log(event);
    }
    reader.onloadstart = function (event) {
      console.log(reader.result);
      console.log(event);
    }
    reader.onloadend = function (event) {
      console.log(reader.result);
      console.log(event);
    }
    reader.onprogress = function (event) {
      console.log(reader.result);
      console.log(event);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (event) {
      console.log(reader.result);
      console.log(event);
      const error = reader.error;
      console.log(error);
    }
    reader.onabort = function (event) {
      console.log(reader.result);
      console.log(event);
    }
  });
```

}

Environment:

- Cordova 12
- Cordova build android@12.0.0 - Android API: 33
- Android Studio: electric eel 2022.1.1
- Angular cli: 5.2.9
- Angular: 13.3.11
- Node 16.14.0

#Could someone please help me? Is there another way to get content file from FileReader()

Comment: Where is the file in your code? I dont see one.